# Choose Items in Security and Privacy

Tags: applescript

I am new to AppleScript and I need to know how to choose options in an Apple Window such as Security and Privacy. Also, I would like to choose the options in a specific order as per the picture attached.

After step 3, the applet needs to put in specific credentials which are hardcoded and continue after that.

I only managed to open the application so far with the below code.

```
    tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
end tell
delay 1
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        click menu item "Security & Privacy" of menu "View" of menu bar 1
        delay 2
        tell window "Security & Privacy"

        end tell
    end tell
end tell
delay 2
```

[image: Security and Privacy]

Comment: Interesting! Apple's Security and Privacy settings probably wouldn't be very effective if it was scriptable... just saying ! _(that's not to suggest in anyway that it is not possible)_

Answer (score 1):

I'm offering this as a *proof of concept* and do not recommend **UI scripting** of **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy**  while hardcoding credentials.

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* was tested under **macOS Catalina**, and worked for me as coded, however, the *value* of the `delay` *commands* may need to be adjusted to work properly on your system.

This *example* **AppleScript** *code* is written to target the **Script Editor** *checkbox* in **Full Disk Access** of: **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy**

Change the *value* of `myUserName` and `myPassword` from `missing value` to the actual user name and password.

```
set myUserName to "missing value"
set myPassword to "missing value"

set nameOfRowToSelect to "Full Disk Access"
set appCheckboxToClick to "Script Editor"

if running of application "System Preferences" then
    try
        tell application "System Preferences" to quit
    on error
        do shell script "killall 'System Preferences'"
    end try
end if

repeat while running of application "System Preferences" is true
    delay 0.1
end repeat

tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    reveal anchor "Privacy" of pane "com.apple.preference.security"
end tell

tell application "System Events" to tell application process "System Preferences"
    repeat while not (exists window "Security & Privacy")
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    tell window "Security & Privacy"
        keystroke "f" using command down
        keystroke tab
        delay 0.25

        select (first row ¬
            of table 1 ¬
            of scroll area 1 ¬
            of tab group 1 ¬
            whose value ¬
            of static text ¬
            of UI element 1 ¬
            contains nameOfRowToSelect)

        delay 0.25
        click button "Click the lock to make changes."
        repeat until exists sheet 1
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
        delay 0.25
        tell sheet 1
            set value of text field 2 to myUserName
            set value of text field 1 to myPassword
            delay 0.25
            click button "Unlock"
            delay 2
        end tell

        click checkbox 1 ¬
            of UI element 1 ¬
            of (first row ¬
            of table 1 ¬
            of scroll area 1 ¬
            of group 1 ¬
            of tab group 1 ¬
            whose (value ¬
            of static text ¬
            of item 1 ¬
            of UI element 1) ¬
            contains appCheckboxToClick)

        repeat until exists sheet 1
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
        delay 0.25
        click button "Later" of sheet 1
        delay 0.25
        click button "Click the lock to prevent further changes."
        delay 0.5
    end tell
end tell

quit application "System Preferences"
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any additional *error* handling as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1).</sub>

Comment: You explained before the benefit of quitting/killing _System Preferences_ first, in order to make transitions less jarring. Would that be needed here ? It seems like you ultimately **do** want _System Preferences_ to be visible, and for it to go to a specific anchor/pane. If _System Preferences_ is already running, `activate` brings it to the foreground, or does nothing; `reveal` switches pane (I'm assuming  in one move, from whichever pane one starts from). Therefore, I'm wondering if, in this case, you can start the functional bits of the script from `activate` ? I could be wrong.

Comment: @CJK I almost always start any AppleScript involving System Preferences with the `if running ...` and `repeat while ...` code blocks you see here for more than one reason, one of which you've mentioned and the other is that there are some modal sheets with some panes and this handles this scenarios too. If the user left a modal sheet open then nothing is going to happen until it's dismissed. I also typically do not use `activate` when there is no need to actually see what is going on, however, there is a need for GUI to be visible here, as the `select` command will fail otherwise.

Comment: I saw the need for `activate`.  The insight about modal sheets is useful information to bear in mind.  Thanks for that.

Comment: @user3439894 is it possible to detect which "row" is currently selected? I would like to detect if the `Accesibility` security is currently being modified